Does Parallelism Always Apply When Using "As Well As"?
Which sentence (or both) is correct between:

Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintain your focus.
Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintaining your focus.

If parallelism is required, then I understand that neither is correct, and the correct version should be: "Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintains your focus". But I have seen other similar instances where parallelism doesn't apply, such as "Anna gives me advice as well as helping me do homework quickly".
Similarly, among:

Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates as well as focus better.
Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates as well as to focus better.
Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates as well as focusing better.

And lastly, between:

I feel comfortable staying at home as well as going outside.
I feel comfortable staying at home as well as go outside.


The first set should be bracketed differently: "Playing sports helps you [stay in shape] as well as [maintain your focus]." It's not "helps" that's in parallel with "maintain": the parallel verbs are "stay" and "maintain." (It might be clearer if you add the optional 'to' before both infinitives: helps you [to] stay... as well as [to] maintain...)

If you really do intend to put "helps" and some form of the verb "maintain" in parallel with each other, then the full sentence would have to be neither of the options you list. Instead, it would be "Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintains your focus." (This seems like a less likely intended meaning than the alternatives.)

In general, parallelism means you should select the same grammatical form in each place. In all of your sets of sentences, this would mean using the same verb form on either side of the phrase "as well as." So, with this in mind, which option do you believe is the best out of each set of alternatives? Which ones use the same form, and which use different forms? If you're still not clear which to choose after asking yourself this question, or if you're having difficulty determining which forms are being used in each case, please edit the question to make it clearer where you're stuck.

@QuackE.Duck Apologize for the way I named the title as this could mislead the reader into thinking that I am trying to apply parallelism rule to the sentences in the question. What I mean when asking this question is that whether parallelism is strictly required when using "as well as". I have done some research myself and found conflicting opinions even among native speakers. I will correct the title of the question for better clarity.

That is a very interesting question then, and one I'm looking forward to reading the answers to! Whether parallelism is an actual grammatical rule or just a stylistic one is something I'm not sure of myself :)

NB The noun is the outdoors.

@KateBunting Edited. Thanks.

Examples 7 and 9 definitely don't work. I think "as well as [gerund]" clauses can be tacked on to non-gerund sentences more flexibly than the reverse, but I can't even say for sure whether sentences like 2 are standard, just that they sound natural. This is a great question.

What matters is that both halves are grammatical if you remove the other half; whether they're parallel is irrelevant. But in practice, you normally use this construction because you want to compare or contrast things, and when comparing and constrasting, it's best to use parallelism, so this is really about good style as much as good grammar.

@the-baby-is-you removed examples 6&7 due to their repetition of examples 1&2, and renamed examples 8&9 to (new) 6&7. Thank you.

This is a good example of why I prefer "and" to "as well as": "as well as" tends to trigger the "-ing" form, leading to ambiguity.  Better: Playing sports helps you stay in shape and maintain your focus or Playing sports helps you stay in shape and maintains your focus.  They mean different things, but there is no ambiguity.

There are specific reasons why some things work and others don't, but I don't think it's because of parallelism. For example:
(1) Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintain your focus.
(2) Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintaining your focus. <-incorrect
(3) Playing sports helps you stay in shape as well as maintains your focus.
In #1, you is the subject. You stay in shape and you maintain your focus.
In #3, Playing sports is the subject. Playing sports helps you and playing sports maintains your focus.
Overall, you can simplify the sentences tremendously by using and instead of as well as. If you don't want to do that, at least do it silently in your mind, because I think the right answer will become more obvious. For example:

Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates as well as and focus better. [OK]
Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates as well as and to focus better. [OK]
Playing sports encourages you to communicate with your teammates  as well as and focusing better. <-incorrect

Similarly:

I feel comfortable staying at home as well as and going outside.[OK]
I feel comfortable staying at home as well as and go outside. <-incorrect

And:

Anna gives me advice as well as and helping me do homework quickly. <-incorrect

You should really make the substitution in this example for it to sound acceptable:

Anna gives me advice and helps me do homework quickly.

Or possibly:

Anna gives me advice, which helps me do homework quickly.
(changing the subject from "Anna" to "advice")


According to your explanation for (2), does it mean this sentence "Anna gives me advice as well as helping me do homework quickly" is also incorrect?

Yes, that sentence is incorrect. It should be "helps" because Anna is the subject.

I added to my answer to include that example.

@ASlowLearner, swmcdonnell: the sentence with "as well as helping" is not incorrect.  See for example this answer to the question Verbs after 'as well as'—is this Merriam-Webster example wrong?.

"Anna gives me advice as well as helping me do homework quickly" is grammatically correct? I disagree. But even if it's technically correct, you would never say that or write that. Ever.
